# Цикл внутри метода append. JS

Tags: javascript, foreach, append

Есть цикл который выводит данные из массива в виде элементов на страницу с помощью метода `append`. Но так как массив многомерный мне понадобилось вывести еще элементы внутри первого `append`. Есть решение в виде создания дополнительного метода, который будет принимать массив и возвращать уже готовую строку после перебора через цикл, но думаю такой вариант не будет верным.

Пример кода:

```
   array.forEach(function(item) {
      $('body').append(function() {
        return '<div class="items-info">' +
        '<div class="items-info-title">' + item.title + '</div>' +
        '<div class="items-info-more">' + 
          item.more.forEach(function(value) {
             return '<div>'+value+'</div>';
          })
        + '</div>' +
        '</div>'
      })
    });
```

Пример массива:

```
{title: "Econom", more: ["Скидка 10%", "Карта"]}
{title: "Normal", more: ["Скидка 15%", "Карта", "Кэшбек 1%"]}
```

Подскажите как привести код в рабочее и правильное состояние

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ничего не возвращает.

Так как тут на основе одного массива получается другой - можно применить метод [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Для его применения достаточно заменить `.forEach` На `.map`.

Так как `map` в данном случае вернет массив строк, а нужна одна большая строка, для их объединения можно воспользоваться методом [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

В итоге код может принять следующий вид:

```
'<div class="items-info-more">' + 
      item.more.map(function(value) {
         return '<div>'+value+'</div>';
      }).join('')
+ '</div>' +
```

Comment: Если впадать в философию, то функции в JS ведь всегда что-то возвращают. Даже в приведённой документации на MDN есть "Возвращаемое значение: undefined")

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
let str = [ 'test', 'string' ].map(item => '<div>' + item + '</div>').join('');

// результат: '<div>test</div><div>string</div>'
```